# css image resize responsive

Tags: html, css, image-gallery

I've made a list with in html. Im trying to display album covers of varying sizes all at 250x250px and have it scale down for mobile. My problem is when I use the code I have the images dont seem to scale down and break out of the div they're in.

```
 <ul id="gallery">
        <li>
        <a href="teethrev.html"><img src="../img/teethun.jpg" alt"">
        </a>
        <p>Teeth- Unremittance</p>
      </li>
        <li>
        <a href="teethrev.html"><img src="../img/teethun.jpg" alt"">
        </a>
        <p>Teeth- Unremittance</p>
      </li>
       <li>
        <a href="teethrev.html"><img src="../img/teethun.jpg" alt"">
        </a>
        <p>Teeth- Unremittance</p>
      </li>
         <li>
        <a href="teethrev.html"><img src="../img/teethun.jpg" alt"">
        </a>
        <p>Teeth- Unremittance</p>
      </li>
        <li>
        <a href="teethrev.html"><img src="../img/teethun.jpg" alt"">
        </a>
        <p>Teeth- Unremittance</p>
      </li>






     /*********************
     Gallery
  *********************/


#gallery {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
list-style:none;
 }

 #gallery li {
float: left;
height: 250px;
width:250px;
margin: 2.5%;
 background-color:#171614;
  }

  #gallery li a p {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5%;
 font-size: 0.75em;
    }
```

Is there any way to display these in a gallery type with just CSS ( i only know css html) and have them be responsive as well. I used the same code from the treehouse tut but they didn't use a div so I don't get how its not working on mine. I also have a global img selector at max-width 100% but I fixed the width to scale these down to the 250x250.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

try it in gallery:

```
margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
width: your width;
height: your height;
margin-top: XXpx;
margin-left: xxpx;
```

and then put the code of the inside parts of the gallery list.

Tell us if it works, I use a similar code and it works to me.

*you have to parametrize your pictures with a css style.

Answer (score 0):

It would help to see more of the CSS, but this should enough:

```
#gallery li img {
    max-width:100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this-

```
#gallery li a img{
margin: 10px;
width:250px;   //desired width
height:250px;   //desired heigth
}
```

There are many other ways but you ahve to specify img styles also..

I hope this will help you...

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend for scale down in mobile something like that:

```css
media only screen and (max-width: 420px) { 
#gallery img {width: 245px; }
}
```

you can set the size of screen that will have this image configuration, it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

maybe so?

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#gallery {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}
#gallery li {
    background-color:#171614;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 23%;
    padding-bottom: 23%;
    margin: 1%;    
}
#gallery li a{
    display: block;    
}
#gallery li img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#gallery li p {
    padding: 5%;
    font-size: 0.75em;
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 800px){
    
    #gallery li {        
        width: 31%;
        padding-bottom: 31%;            
    }        
    
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px){
    
    #gallery li {        
        width: 48%;
        padding-bottom: 48%;            
    }        
    
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 360px){
    
    #gallery li {        
        width: 98%;
        padding-bottom: 98%;            
    }        
    
}
```

```html
<ul id="gallery">
    <li> <a href="teeth.html">
            <img src="http://s3-media4.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/GJ5d_uEBpZUEOxjH390a8Q/ls.jpg" alt="" />
        </a>

        <p>Teeth- Unremittance</p>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="teethrev.html"><img src="http://s3-media4.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/GJ5d_uEBpZUEOxjH390a8Q/ls.jpg" alt="" />
        </a>

        <p>Teeth- Unremittance</p>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="teethrev.html"><img src="http://s3-media4.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/GJ5d_uEBpZUEOxjH390a8Q/ls.jpg" alt="" />
        </a>

        <p>Teeth- Unremittance</p>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="teethrev.html"><img src="http://s3-media4.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/GJ5d_uEBpZUEOxjH390a8Q/ls.jpg" alt="" />
        </a>

        <p>Teeth- Unremittance</p>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="teethrev.html"><img src="http://s3-media4.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/GJ5d_uEBpZUEOxjH390a8Q/ls.jpg" alt="" />
        </a>

        <p>Teeth- Unremittance</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

close tag `ul` - `</ul>`